# How does Infamous 2 change based on the way I played Infamous 1?

Tags: infamous, infamous-2

It's [been said](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/05/27/infamous-2-imports-your-infamous-trophy-data-to-grant-rewards-a/) that having certain Infamous 1 tropies will *"result in changes in side missions, Dead Drops and dialogue"*.  What are these side-missions, dead-drops, and dialogue, specifically?  How significant of an impact does it have on the story-line/gameplay?

I ask because I beat the game before I had a PS3, so I don't have the trophies on my account.  It drives me crazy knowing I might be missing out on some of the story-line.

Comment: InFamous is always worth another playthrough, and it's free as part of the Welcome Back program!

Answer (score 3):

The changes in the Dead Drops and Dialogues reference your karma alignment from the first game. Without spoiling too much here I can say that the dialogue in dead drops refer to your actions in Empire City depending on whether you were good or evil. Similarly a couple of conversations in the game with Zeke and Kuo.

This is the first I have heard of that side missions are also affected by trophies from Infamous 1. I have only finished my first play through of Infamous 2 on 'Good'. Maybe somebody who has finished the game on both good and evil can correct me if I am wrong but I don't think the side missions change depending on your Infamous 1 trophies. They are different based on your current karma alignment and whether you choose to do the Good or Evil Side missions.

Answer (score 0):

I finished **Infamous 1** about a month ago, starting on Good and ending with Evil. In **Infamous 2**, I started with Evil and finished it. I'm close to finishing Good, and I'm finding there are more side missions available on the Good side. The dead drop tapes also change depending on your alignment, in addition to your interaction with Zeke, Kuo and Nix. Similar to **Infamous 1**, you have good and evil missions that are paired and will lock out the other if you choose one. That being said, I also believe there are more Good missions than Evil ones.

One other note: you can't achieve 100% completion of the game unless you finish both Good and Evil.